# Reading image file via Socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, file-transfer

I am trying to read an image file via a Python socket. My current attempt is the following:

```
while True:
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    receivedMessage = (data.decode(encoding='UTF-8')).strip()
    if ("getFile" in receivedMessage):
        f = open("test2.jpg","wb")
        file_size = int(receivedMessage.replace('getFile',''))
        # Message: e.g. getFile28049994
        read_bytes = 0
        print("READING FILE")
        while file_size > read_bytes:
            print("RECEIVING FILE")
            bytes_read = clientsocket.recv(1024)
            if not bytes_read:
                print("END OF FILE")
            print("CHECKPOINT") # this is never printed out
            read_bytes = len(bytes_read)
            #writing to file
```

The file is sent via Android as a byte array:
Client class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Exception exception;
    private byte[] data;
    private String dataString;
    public Client(MainActivity activity,byte[] data){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Client(MainActivity activity,String dataString){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dataString = dataString;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... command) {
        try{
            Socket client = new Socket(".....", 50000);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            if (data != null){
                out.print(data);
            }
            if (dataString != null){
                out.println(dataString);
            }
            String receivedMessage;
            if ((receivedMessage = in.readLine()) != null){
                if (receivedMessage.equals("connectionSuccessful")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("sendServerMessage");
                    intent.putExtra("msg",receivedMessage);
                    activity.sendBroadcast(intent);

                }
                Log.e("Debug",receivedMessage);
            }

            client.close();
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("Exception","Unknown host");

        }
        catch(ConnectException e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("sendServerMessage");
            intent.putExtra("msg","connectionFailed");
            activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.e("Exception","No I/O"+e);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Exception",""+e);

        }
        return null;
     }

}
```

And the execution of the client:

```
new Client(activity, bytes).execute(); // bytes is a byte array (checked it)
```

Any idea why it is not received? Is it because I am calling two times clientsocket.recv? And how could I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what is actually send. It is unclear what happens in your code. All you do is dump some code here and claim that it does not work. There are no details on what you expect, what happens instead and how the problem can be reproduced. There is one obvious thing though: you seem to assume that `recv` will exactly match a `send` on the other side, i.e. you assume that the first read will have exactly the command inside, no more and no less. This kind of semantic is not true with TCP since TCP has no idea of messages, only bytes.

Comment: I added the code for the client on Android. The communication for messages works well. But there are problems when I send a bigger file.

Comment: *"... there are problems ..."* - again, this is not a usable error description. It is basically only saying "does not work", without providing any way to understand what exactly does not work and how to reproduce it.

Comment: I simply get no console output for the byte array. So the socket seems to have problems to receive the byte array.

Comment: In other words: you made no attempt to debug your code. You just assumed that it should work and when it does not you did not look at the various parts of your code to check if your expectations (like how many bytes should have been read, how large is the buffer ...) matches what actually happens. I recommend that you exactly do this, i.e. make yourself clear what you expect from the various parts of your code and then check the expectation is matched by reality. If not try to understand why not. If you cannot understand it provide __all__ the details so far here so that others can help.